# How to update $scope value fro directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I a creative directives dynamically in loop.  where each each input name created dynamically. 
In the same I want to update scope value as per question. $scope object name should by dynamic. like $scope.answers.xxx
where xxx is question name.
$scope.question have all question
and want to maintain answers in $scope.answers.

Directive function

```
function textControlDir()
{
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        /*scope: {
            queObj: '=',
            selectedAns: '='
        },*/
        template: '<div class="form-group">\n\
            <label for="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{queObj._text}}</label>\n\
            <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}" value="{{selectedAns}}"></div>\n\
        </div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var queObj = scope.que.QuestionData;
            scope.queObj = scope.que.QuestionData; 
            scope.name = queObj._attributeName;
            scope.id = queObj._attributeName;
            var selectedAns = '';
            if(scope.answers)
            {
                selectedAns = scope.answers[scope.name];
            }
            if(selectedAns && selectedAns != '')
            {
                scope.selectedAns = selectedAns;
            }
            else
            {
                scope.selectedAns = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
            } 
        }
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
        <text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData" ></text-control-dir>
    </div>  
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'select'" >
        <select-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></select-control-dir>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'radio'" >
        <radio-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></radio-control-dir>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'hidden' && que.QuestionData._attributeName != 'CBQ'" >
        <hidden-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></hidden-control-dir>
    </div>
</div>
```

Created plunker for complete code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Comment: Why do you want so many directives? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I created only four directives. html i a creating i loop. there are many inputs. so created questions set and looping it. Please see plunker.

Comment: Can you describe in brief , your requirement

Comment: In $scope.questions have all question, I am looping in index.html. for each question i am creating a input. if $scope.answers have value for particular input I am showing in input box. this much is working. Now I want set value in answers if user changes anything in input box.

Comment: You dont need directives for it, controller will do the job for you

Comment: how can I do using controller. input box html created from directive.

Comment: where should i write controller here.

Answer (score 1):

Scope updation from the link function is impossible without a `scope.$apply` or `ngModelController`

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="que.QuestionData.Answer">
    </div>  
</div>


var app = angular.module("app",[]);

var ctrlFn = function(){
$scope.questions = questions;\\assign scope here

};
var ctrl = app.contoller('ctrl',ctrlFn);

ctrlFn.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: Directive in pluner are different. ng-model not working in that. Can you please try with plunker.

Comment: Directives are not needed, in your case have the answer as input's model if at all answer is present, value will be auto filled

Comment: i need to go with directive as easy to maintain repeated code. nad light weight do.  In my case only ng-model is not working can we write some code in link to update answers

Comment: trying like <text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData" data-ng-model="answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]"></text-control-dir>

Comment: Your code is not light weight, Angular is used widely because of the change detection. you are killing that attribute

Comment: or insight directive if scope.answers[scope.name] = element.val or through controller if we could make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$scope.answers[questionName] = data;
```

Comment: `$scope` is not available in the directive's link function.

Comment: I am suing parent scope in directive, can u please check plunker.